# Why are the <li>s becoming wider than the images in Firefox when the scrollbar is displayed?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have this horizontal image list with numbers and a scrollbar:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: #242424;
  list-style: none;

  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px;
  padding-right: 0;

  overflow-x: auto;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
  scrollbar-color: #a7a7a7 #242424;
}

ul::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 6px;
}
ul::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: #242424;
}
ul::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #a7a7a7;
}

ul:focus {
  outline: none;
}

li {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 12px;
  position: relative;
}

li img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}

li .index {
  position: absolute;
  right: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px black, -1px -1px black, -1px 1px black, 1px -1px black;
}
```

```html
<ul style="height: 200px;">
<li>
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/600/any?0">
  <span class="index">1</span>
</li>
<li>
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/600/any?1">
  <span class="index">2</span>
</li>
<li>
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/600/any?2">
  <span class="index">3</span>
</li>
<li>
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/600/any?3">
  <span class="index">4</span>
</li>
<li>
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/600/any?4">
  <span class="index">5</span>
</li>
<li>
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/600/any?5">
  <span class="index">6</span>
</li>
<li>
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/600/any?6">
  <span class="index">7</span>
</li>
<li>
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/600/any?7">
  <span class="index">8</span>
</li>
<li>
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/600/any?8">
  <span class="index">9</span>
</li>
<li>
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/600/any?9">
  <span class="index">10</span>
</li>
<li>
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/600/any?10">
  <span class="index">11</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

In Chromium it works perfectly, but in Firefox the `<li>`s become wider than the images when the scrollbar is displayed! Try to remove some images so that there is no overflow - the distance between the images will be exactly 12px in Firefox too. But when the scrollbar is displayed, the `<li>`s will be wider than the images in Firefox and therefore the numbers are positioned incorrectly.

How can I make it look correctly in Firefox and Chromium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Firefox.
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1680049

Answer (score -1):

I see a couple of things going on here that would explain your issue.

First of all, your `<li>`s have a `padding-right: 12px`, which means they're always going to be bigger than the image. You need to use a `margin-right` instead, so that the space is outside the element's container, rather than inside.

Second, you have a `<span>` in the `<li>` after the `<img>`, which, as an inline element, is also going to push the width of the `<li>` unless you set a fixed width for each `<li>` or actively push the `<span>` to the next line with CSS, a `<br>`, or wrapping it in a block element like a `<div>` or a `<p>`.

Comment: Sorry, I've written 8px instead of 12px by mistake. Now I've also replaced the padding with margin because that makes the question clearer. The `<span>` is positioned absolutely, so will it really affect the container's width?

Comment: When I remove the `<span>`s with the numbers, there's still the same problem

Comment: The problem is that neither the `<img>` elements nor the `<li>`s have any width set. If you specify a fixed width on the images (I found 320px to be best) it will work properly.

Comment: Thank you! But that works only if the images have a fixed width, but the height of the list can change, and then the width of the images also changes.

Comment: Should I use JS to change the width of the images when the list changes its height?